# Can we use flatMapGroupsWithState in batch mode?

Tags: apache-spark

Can we use `flatMapGroupsWithState` in batch mode?

We have been using `flatMapGroupsWithState` API to do sessionization of our click stream data. Now we are planning to use it to run in Batch Mode.

For more context check this video posted by [Bartosz Konieczny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9726075/bartosz-konieczny?tab=profile) in youtube [Using Apache Spark to Solve Sessionization Problem in Batch and Streaming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iajzckThnm4&t=1730s)

Can we get rid off the `full-outer` join and use `mapGroupWithState` with a `checkpoint folder` and Spark State

Comment: What would be the point of this? The state object `GroupState` for a batch dataset will be empty as there is no prior state, i.e. it will be equivalent to simple `flatMapGroups()`.

Comment: We are planning to run a sequential job where the batch (i+1) will depend upon batch (i). and both batch (i) and batch (i+1) will be materialized in HDFS in different time

Answer (score 0):

> Can we get rid off the full-outer join and use mapGroupWithState with a checkpoint folder and Spark State

Yes, if the source is supported in Structured Streaming. You can add the `Trigger.Once` and coordinate the execution from your data orchetsration layer in "batch" mode.
But since every job execution will start by loading all active state from the state store to Spark shuffle partitions, in the end it's quite similar to performing full-outer join with still active sessions. Unless, you want to reduce the latency and use streaming with a controlled execution? Can you explain a bit why you want to switch?

Best,
Bartosz.

Comment: We want to follow a Lambda pattern and have same code base for streaming and batch. But I guess flatMapGroupWithState cannot load an initial state. Thanks

Comment: No, there is no possibility to define the initial state globally, except doing that by state group, in the mapping function, for example by fetching it from a remote fast-access data store like a key-value or in-memory.  But it will not load the state for the keys that are missing in the input data.